# Different versions of Django are imported when Run and Debug in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I want to upgrade a Django project from Django 1.2.5 to Django 1.11 on a server, and I added a remote project interpreter in Pycharm on my local machine. In order to switch between Django 1.2.5 and Django 1.11 conveniently, I downloaded the source code of Django 1.11 and added it to `sys.path` in `manage.py` by

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'Django_1_11')
```

where `Django_1_11` is the folder of source code. When I Run my project, it works and Django 1.11 is imported. But when I Debug my project, Django 1.2.5 is imported even if `Django_1_11` is in the `sys.path`. How can I import Django 1.11 in the Debug mode?

Comment: please start using virtualenvs

Comment: Upgrading directly from 1.2 to 1.11 is most likely going to be impossible, you should incrementally upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding the directory  `Django_1_11` to `PYTHONPATH`.